# Promise confusion using node (ES6) and Bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I had an issue with values being assigned prior to an async call being complete, so I opted to use Promises (in this instance: Bluebird). Which I thought would solve the problem, but seeing as I'm not at all familiar with promises / or node for that matter, it's still doing the same thing.

How would I go about modifying my code below, to use promises correctly? And maintain a flow, so I can validate `modules` based upon a previous `row` ?

```
var Promise         = require('bluebird');
var db              = require('../shared/db');
var queryHelper     = require('../shared/queryHelper');
var schemas         = require('../schemas/schemas');
var _               = require('lodash');
var serverSettings  = require('../shared/coreServerSettings');

// Create new instance of mysql module
var connection      = new db();
var queryhelper     = new queryHelper();

// Promised methods
var queryAndWait = Promise.promisify(connection.query);
```

..snip..

```
queryAndWait(query + '; ' + queryFoundRows, params).then(function (result) {
  var payload = [];
  var site_access = [];
  var module_access = [];

  _.each(result[0], function (row) {
    var sites = row.site_access.split(',');
    _.each(sites, function (site_id) {
      site_access.push(site_id);
    });

    row.site_access = site_access;
    site_access = [];

    queryAndWait(queryModules, [row.priv_id]).then(function (result) {
      _.each(result, function (module) {
        var modulePriv = {
          priv_name: module.priv_name,
          priv_num: module.priv_num,
          enabled: module.enabled
        };

        module_access.push(modulePriv);
      });

      //console.log("am assigning " + JSON.stringify(module_access));
      row.module_access = module_access;
      module_access = []
    });

    payload.push(row);
  });
});
```

To clarify:

Sorry, modules are groups of products that users (row) have access to, which are calculated on the fly (bitwise - hence no join available and a separate query), the module query returns something like the following, which I then loop through and attach to the row prior to returning the payload:

```
[{"priv_name":"INTERACT","priv_num":1,"enabled":1},{"priv_name":"STAFF_ADMIN","priv_num":32,"enabled":1},{"priv_name":"INT_EDIT","priv_num":64,"enabled":0},{"priv_name":"FAILED_LOGIN","priv_num":128,"enabled":0},{"priv_name":"INT_TAGS","priv_num":256,"enabled":0},{"priv_name":"NC","priv_num":512,"enabled":0},{"priv_name":"CC_TIMETABLE_MGR","priv_num":1024,"enabled":0}]
```

Comment: What is `modules` and what is the expected output?

Comment: Have updated to clarify

Comment: Just a Sidenote, all lodash functions you are using here are natively implemented in JavaScript, no need for a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, the inner `queryAndWait` will run independently for each row as you don't chain the promises.

Since you use bluebird you'll need something like this to maintain the flow

```
queryAndWait(query + '; ' + queryFoundRows, params).then(function (result) {
    return Promise.map(result[0], function (row) {
        var site_access = [];
        var module_access = [];

        var sites = row.site_access.split(',');
        _.each(sites, function (site_id) {
            site_access.push(site_id);
        });

        row.site_access = site_access;

        return queryAndWait(queryModules, [row.priv_id]).then(function (result) {
            _.each(result, function (module) {
                var modulePriv = {
                    priv_name: module.priv_name,
                    priv_num: module.priv_num,
                    enabled: module.enabled
                };

                module_access.push(modulePriv);
            });
            row.module_access = module_access;
            return row;
        });
    });
}).then(function(payload) {
    console.log(payload);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: `row.site_access = row.site_access.split(',');`. Reading across into another array is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Promise help you to control de flow of the application in a simple way. I encourage you to read the basic principles about promise, at least the Promise A+ specification.

Your code could be written in many ways this is the way that I recommend because is modular:

```
var Promise         = require('bluebird');
var queryAndWait = Promise.promisify(connection.query);

function getRows(params) {
  return queryAndWait(query + '; ' + queryFoundRows, params)
          .then(function (result) {
            var site_access = [];
            _.each(result[0], function (row) {
              var sites = row.site_access.split(',');
              _.each(sites, function (site_id) {
                site_access.push(site_id);
              });
              row.site_access = site_access;
              site_access = [];
              return row;
            });
          });
}


function getModules(row) {
 return queryAndWait(queryModules, [row.priv_id])
         .then(function (result) {
          var payload = [];
          var module_access = [];
          _.each(result, function (module) {
            var modulePriv = {
              priv_name: module.priv_name,
              priv_num: module.priv_num,
              enabled: module.enabled
            };

            module_access.push(modulePriv);
          });              
          row.module_access = module_access;

          payload.push(row);
          return payload;
        });
}

getRows(params)
  .then(getModules)
  .then(function(payload) {
    // Do something with your payload
  })
```

I did the next:

1. Separate each logic in his own function (Why?, Because you can reuse logic in another promise, export methods in another libraries, etc.)
2. I return the promise in each function. The promise can be nested and are executed in order.
3. Each intern promise resolve a value. getRows -> resolve rows, getModules -> resolve a payload

You can also manage the erros using the catch method of promises, for example:

```
getRows(params)
  .catch(function(err) {
    // Something went wrong with getRows
    // If i can't recovery must return a reject.
  })
  .then(getModules)
  .catch(function(err) {
    //Something went wrong with getModules
    // If i can't recovery must return a reject.
  })
  .then(function(payload) {
    // Do something with your payload
  })
```